# Different file kinds for same kind(/type) of files

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, finder, php, bbedit

I am seeing this weird thing on Mac (OSX). I have a PHP project where the file kind of certain PHP is listed as PHP where as other listed as TextWrangler text document; although all PHP files are associated with TextWrangler.

The problem I am facing with PHP files being listed as different kinds is when arranging/sorting files based on file kind.

Is there a way to fix this - make the file kind of all PHP files as PHP?

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

Comment: Do the PHP files listed as TextWrangler text documents have a ".php" extension included on them? Do the other PHP files correctly listed have one?

Comment: Yeah, the files listed as PHP and TextWrangler text document both have .php extension on them.

Comment: I have a similar issue. In my case I have a folder of files and the "Kind" shows up as "Document". I copy them to a folder in a network location (A GoFlex Home drive) and the very same files say they are of Kind = "Unix Executable File". I'm curious if you have figured out a fix for your PHP files.

Comment: Nope I haven't. :( I am being asked to get used to :(